# using protobuf as a textual configuraton file

Tags: configuration-files, protocol-buffers

I recently encountered a very large mission-critical project where all the configuration
files were defined using textual protobuf definitions. The configuration files are meant to be 
human readable and editable.

For example

```
message ServerSettings {
  required int32 port = 3022;
  optional string name = "mywebserver";
}
```

Personally I found this humorous.
But is it in fact a reasonable keep-it-simple technique, or clearly moronic ?!

In other words, are there REAL, ACTUAL problems with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the text proto if format, then... Whatever, I guess. If it works, then it is as reasonable as any other serialization format.

If that is meant to be proto schema, then it is illegal (the value after the = is meant to be the field number).

Json or XML might be more typical, but as long as it works it isn't "moronic". So the ultimate question is: does it work?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's quite clever. I am guessing they pass it through protoc --encode to generate a binary which is what is actually parsed.

Pros:
1. Code is generated to parse configuration
2. Type validation
3. More robust configuration file compared to a key/value as it supports structs, unions, maps and arrays
4. The configuration data is now serializable meaning it can be easily exposed to an RPC or IPC interface.

Cons:
1. The syntax can be a little verbose for maps/arrays.
2. It requires protoc to be installed on the target as well as libprotobuf.so if you are on a system with tight memory limits.