# protobuf for configuration files

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, configuration-files

Related to [using protobuf as a textual configuraton file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873653/using-protobuf-as-a-textual-configuraton-file) I'd like to use protobuf for configuration file.

I expect that protobuf allows me to use simple parser with exact structure.

My configuration structure looks like

```
//my.proto    
package my_config; 

message MyConfigItem {
  required string type = 1;
  required string name = 2;
  repeated string inputNames = 3 [packed=true];
  repeated string outputNames = 4 [packed=true];
}
```

And bunch of different items in config files like

```
MyConfigItem {
  type = "type1";
  name = "name1";
  inputNames = {"input1", "input2"};
}
```

What's the best way for organizing that?

Comment: `how to initialize null value?` Just omit that field completely.

Comment: `how to initialize array?` `{ "input1", "input2" };`

Comment: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: What is your question now? I don't get what you mean with _"best way for organizing"_?

Comment: Am I understand right that I need:
1. Compile .proto file using protoc
2. Create config file as .prototxt with items like described above
3. Add something to my project for parsing this file _(maybe create additional class for it ?)_

Comment: `protoc` already generates a class you can use to read that textfile.

Comment: If it'll be a set of different `MyConfigItem` in one file, protoc-generated class can parse it one by one or I should create structure like
`message Items { optional repeated MyConfigItem = 1; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write config file like:

```
  type : "type1"
  name : "name1"
  inputNames : {"input1", "input2"}
```

So I think that you must use ':' instead of '=', and "do not" write the items wrapped in the brackets.